# IntelliJ Idea debugger's evaluator gives different results than normal program for comparing Scala Long and Float variables

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

[image]

As the screenshot shows, While I'm comparing the same literal values with type of Float and Long, Scala says it's not equal

But the evaluator says they are equal to each other!

I suspect this is a bug in Intellij Idea, since the same code will yield different results in a normal Scala runtime than in a evaluator runtime.

If the Evaluator's result is untrustworthy, this may cause trouble for developers.

I wonder if there is anything wrong with my thinking and hope someone can point it out.

Comment: Looks like you are correct. I suggest submitting a bug report to JetBrains.

Comment: Thank you, I've submitted, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-299924/IntelliJ-Idea-evaluator-runtime-gives-different-results-than-normal-program-runtime-while-comparing-JavaScala-Long-and-Float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not reproduce your example using the Intellij evaluator (though I don't use a Mac, this might be a bug on the Mac version of Intellij), but what I can say is that Java and Scala treat this differently. Actually, in Scala 2.13.x those values are equal.

Java treats this code differently based on their types (primitive vs wrapper types):

```
    long vl = 32294629407L;
    float vf = 32294629407f;
    Boolean res11 = vl == vf;
    System.out.println(res11); // true

    Long vl1 = 32294629407L;
    Float vf1 = 32294629407f;
    Boolean res22 = vl1.equals(vf1);
    System.out.println(res22); // false
```

Since Scala was designed to be a more regular language, such discrepancies were removed from the language, by special casing the `==` method for these classes:

```
  val vl: Long  = 32294629407L
  val vf: Float = 32294629407f
  val res11     = vl == vf // true 

  println(res11) // true
```

> The only case where == does not directly call `equals` is for Java's
> boxed numeric types.

**NOTE**:

For prior versions of Scala, this does not hold, as it seems in Scala 2.12 this is not valid.

Comment: I'm using Scala 2.12.0, the result is in contrast with yours.

Could it be version dependent?

Comment: Ok, I tested this on Scala 2.13.8. It appears to be version dependent. At least what I wrote here is from the Scala 2.13 update - Programming in Scala , 4th edition.

Comment: Ah.  I tried Scala 2.13.8, you are right ,
They are equal in 2.13.8 , 
but not equal in 2.12.0

Comment: It's reasonable for Scala has broken changes between 2.12 and 2.13.
But for Intellij Idea, the different results in Evaluator runtime and normal runtime is  still confusing

Comment: I don't know how Intellij Idea's Debug subsystems works,  But obviously it has different Scala runtime of the Evaluator and the normal process.